# XmlPullParser parse node with multiple types

Tags: android, android-xml, xmlpullparser

Please someone help me to parse this block of code using android's XmlPullParser (nothing else):

```
<div fontStyle="normal">
    <p textAlign="center">
        <span fontSize="26">dontneedthis</span>
    </p>
    <p>description1</p>
    <p>description2</p>
    <p>description3</p>
</div>
```

I need to get only concatenated description1+description2+description3

Seems very easy, but I have problems skipping  `<p textAlign="center">...</p>` because I dont need that and get only other `<p>`'s TEXT

The whole document is huge, I've parsed all other parts except this one. Ive wrote some code, its huge, parsing is working (and I can get what exactly I need just with few nodes). Document is huge and its hard to catch the error. Maybe your alternative code can help me.

[This](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) is a good tutorial, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda Thanks Ive solved my problem. Please see my answer. The problem wasn't in code. Ive change parser class from KXmlParser to XmlBlock  (without changing code - they implement same interface). It seems KXmlParser has limitation on the reading (seeking?) data...

Comment: Why at all you are using foreign pull parer on android?    There is one provided by  system

Comment: Its not foreign pull parer (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#choose)

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967062/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-androids-kxmlparser). KXmlParser (implementation of the XmlPullParser) throws error when it cursor position gets 8192. Its a limit. I didnt find any documentation how to change this limit. So now Im using compile xml file (XmlBlock implementation of the XmlPullParser)