# Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException only on Panasonic P-02E

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I gather crashes by Firebase for all my apps. One of them reported following error, but what is weird, only on device Panasonic P-02E. I have no idea what part of my code is reponsible for this, but it seem to be problem of Panasonic only, not application. Any idea how to fix this?

```
Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=8192 srcPos=1 
dst.length=8192 dstPos=0 length=-1
java.lang.System.arraycopy (System.java)
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer (KXmlParser.java:1489)
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.skip (KXmlParser.java:1574)
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.parseStartTag (KXmlParser.java:1049)
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next (KXmlParser.java:369)
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next (KXmlParser.java:310)
com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisMapXml (XmlUtils.java:578)
com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisValueXml (XmlUtils.java:821)
com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readValueXml (XmlUtils.java:755)
com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readMapXml (XmlUtils.java:494)
android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:113)
android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$000 (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:48)
android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1.run (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:87)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another note on stackoverflow with the same issue.  Seems to be related to a bug around the XML download cutting out and Android not throwing up the right exception.  Not sure if this will help: 
[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in android's KXmlParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967062/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-androids-kxmlparser)